# How to supress EAccessViolation Finalization exception (mshtml.dll)

Tags: delphi, exception, twebbrowser

We use TWebBrowser in our application.

on some of my customers computers (IE9/Win7) after my app terminates, it throws an Exception: `"Access violation at address XXXX in module 'mshtml.dll'. Read of address XXXX"` with endless loop of exception messages... very ugly :/

this only happens on very few computers (so far with only IE9/Win7). 
I cannot reproduce this exception on my PC.

I also use `JclDebug` which is the last unit defined in my main dpr uses clause - it is not catching this exception.

How to completely supress this Exception?

The application is written in D5.

Comment: (Just a quick note: JCLDebug probably wouldn't catch the exception if the problem you're encountering is within Delphi's finalization process. The key to better tracking the problem down would be to move the error out of the finalization sequence -- i.e., destroy the web browser component before closing yourself down. )

Comment: Plus having the JclDebug as the last unit in the dpr means it will be the last unit to initialize and the first to finalize (unless units coming before it in the dpr have it in their interface uses clause which would move it forward in the initialization order and back in the finalization order). Putting it as the first unit (after any memory managers) in your dpr would help to catch errors in the initialization/finalization of other units.

Comment: @MarjanVenema, I see what you mean, but as far as I remember all examples of JclDebug used ExceptDlg as the last unit. using it as the first unit caused me problems and unexpected crashes. I am now checking into madExcept also.

Comment: There is for sure a VCL bug that can result in AVs on shutdown. If you rely on the Application ownership to destroy your forms on shutdown then you can run into them. So definitely try putting a call to `MainForm.Free`, or `FreeAndNil(MainForm)` if you prefer ;-) as the final action of the code in your .dpr file. Or if `MainForm.Free` isn't enough, destroy everything that's yours.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wild guess... there is a callback (event) from IE when your Application is in the destructor and your TWebBrowser is (at least partially) destroyed.
You can try to explicitly Free the TWebBrowser earlier, see if you have any event handler that could mess around, make sure you use Release on the form that holds it...

Hard to tell without having the code.

Comment: Your guess about the IE was pretty much right. I was setting a `TDocHostUIHandler` via `document.SetUIHandler`. then Freeing it before Freeing the TWebBrowser. Thanks.